# List comprehension for appending 2 elements of 2 different lists next to each other

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to create a list comprehension, to create a list where 2 elements of 2 different lists are appended next to each other?

```
For instance, if you have 2 lists:
suits = ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
value_suits = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

# 1 element at a time for 1 list is possible in a list comprehension:
deck = [value for value in value_suits]   

#but can you also do something like this(with correct syntax):
deck = [suit,value for suit,value in suits,value_suits]

#such that you get the same output as:
deck = []

for suit in ["Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]:
    for value in ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]:
        deck.append(str(value)+" "+suit)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have nested list comprehensions:

```
deck = ['{} {}'.format(value, suit) for suit in suits for value in value_suits]
```

You can also use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

deck = ['{1} {0}'.format(*sv) for sv in product(suits, value_suits)]
```